# How to get point of interest near my point using overpass-api?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, point-of-interest

I am using Overpass API.

I have an issue to find some points of interest (cafes, hospitals, schools) near (around in 100-200 miles) my point. I have only latitude and longitude.

Overpass API gives opportunity to get POIs using your place name. But I don't have it. I have only coordinates.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [around](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Around) statement!

```
<query type="node">
  <around lat="..." lon="..." radius="..."/>
  <has-kv k="amenity" v="cafe" />
</query>
<print />
```

Try this example on [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/8g)!

Comment: Can you please help with one more issue. How to set several keys & values. For example I need amenity cafe and bank. And also "historic" keys with value f.e. "battlefield" ? So in the result I need cafes, banks and battlefields. Thanks

Comment: _Logic or_ for a particular key is best done with a little trick: use a [regular expression](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#One_or_another_name) like `<has-kv k="amenity" regv="cafe|bank"/>`. _Logic or_ for different keys has to be done by `<union>`ing multiple `<query>`s. Like in this [example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9L).