# Overpass API - filter out non-empty tags

Tags: overpass-api, point-of-interest

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442663/how-to-get-point-of-interest-near-my-point-using-overpass-api), I am trying to query the Overpass API so that it returns all nodes with tags "natural" and "historic" where tag "name" is not emtpy around a set of coordinates with radius 1500m

What I have so far is

```
<union>
    <query type="node">
        <around radius="1500" lat="51.1263041473" lon="1.3268128927"/>
        <has-kv k="historic"/>
    </query>
    <query type="node">
        <around radius="1500" lat="51.1263041473" lon="1.3268128927"/>
        <has-kv k="natural"/>
    </query>
</union>
<print/>
```

This works for both keywords, but doesn't cater for tag "name" not being empty (see: [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hUi))

How can I filter out any node with tag "name" not emtpy?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I just found the answer - I didn't know how to put regex into the query. Now I do:

```
<union>
<query type="node">
    <around radius="1500" lat="51.1263041473" lon="1.3268128927"/>
    <has-kv k="historic"/>
    <has-kv k="name" regv=".+"/>      
</query>
<query type="node">
    <around radius="1500" lat="51.1263041473" lon="1.3268128927"/>
    <has-kv k="natural"/>
    <has-kv k="name" regv=".+"/>
</query>
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `<has-kv k="name"/>`? There's really not much reason for a regex in this case.